# Visual studio publish error does not include sqllite file

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2017

Local database sqllite .db file does not appear when publish project and when I try to add it from application files option it does not appear with files.

[image]

please pay attention that the program is work properly

Comment: Did you add them to project tree?

Comment: how can I do that

Comment: You can try to add the "sqlite" file into the project in "Solution Explorer".